# Kubelet don't auth using TLS

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster on Ubuntu VMs using Docker.

Without TLS, it work fine (on port 8080).

I use Let's Encrypt for secure API Server (port 6443), it's work ! My problem appear when my Kubelet want auth to the master using https.

This is how I launch Kubelet Api Server :

```
    /hyperkube apiserver 
--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.1/24 
--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1 
--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:4001 
--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota 
--client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt 
--basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv 
--min-request-timeout=300 
--tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert 
--tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key 
--token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv 
--allow-privileged=true --v=4
```

And this is how I launch Kubelet :

```
  /hyperkube kubelet \
        --allow-privileged=true \
        --api-servers=https://k8:6443 \
        --kubeconfig=/srv/kubernetes/config.yaml \
        --v=2 \
        --address=0.0.0.0 \
        --enable-server \
        --containerized \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=k8.local
```

Here is the config.yaml file :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: k8.local
  cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://k8:6443
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: "k8.local"
    user: "node1"
  name: development
current-context: development
users:
- name: node1
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/run/kubernetes/kubelet.crt
    client-key: /var/run/kubernetes/kubelet.key
```

When I launch my Kubelet, logs says :
`the server has asked for the client to provide credentials`.

I think I'm wrong with Kubelet's certs but I don't understand why.

Can you help me ?

10xx.

Answer (score 0):

Were your client certs (/var/run/kubernetes/kubelet.crt) signed by the CA file identified in: --client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt?

Also, you might try replacing

```
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://k8:6443
```

with:

```
- cluster
    certificate-authority: /srv/kubernetes/ca.crt
    server: https://k8:6443
```

I've never used basic auth or token auth, but it's possible having those flags in place is requiring password based authentication.   I'd try removing these as well if you're doing purely cert based authentication.

```
--basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv 
--token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

The certs in /var/run/kubernetes are here by default. I think this is the problem, they are no link with my Api server's certs.

I have try with only basic auth, but it doesn't work.



How to generate node certs signed by my ca.pem file ? I have to use Let's Encrypt ?

Comment: We've been using [cfssl](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) to create our certificates.   It's quite easy to automate certificate creation with policy files.  In fact, when I create new clusters, they all get new certificates, even the CA certs.   

However, for Let's Encrypt, the process is similar.  You submit a CSR to them.   When they return your certs, you should have:

1.  Your signed certificate
2.  A CA certificate chain (or pointer to it, it is probably available on their website).  

Also, makes the cert at --tls-cert-file for apiserver includes the CA (cert then CA).

Comment: I have try with cfssl using this tutorial : https://github.com/kelseyhightower/docker-kubernetes-tls-guide 
I have already these logs in Kubelet containers :

 `Unable to register node1.k8 with the apiserver: Post https://k8:6443/api/v1/nodes: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`